# Последовательность в CSS Transition

Tags: css, transition

CSS Transitions это отличное средство, но добиться его гибкости порой непросто.

Например, есть HTML-элемент со значением прозрачности по умолчанию, что равно единице.

Назначаем ему `transition-property: opacity` и `transition-duration: .5s`
На данном этапе, при любом изменении значения прозрачности (для примера, это событие `:hover`), переход будет происходить в течении 500 милисекунд, как мы и указали.

Но что если нужно моментально скрыть элемент, а потом плавно показать его?

```css
.elem {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:#333;
  transition:opacity .5s;
}
.elem:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="elem"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока думал над логикой происходящего, ответ пришел сам, но всё же решил опубликовать, вдруг кому пригодится.
Решение было в разделении свойств transition, что дает возможность гибко манипулировать ими (свойствами), например изменять только их в добавляемом классе (или псевдоклассе, как в примере).

```css
.elem {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:#333;
  transition-property:opacity;
  transition-duration:.5s;
}
.elem:hover {
  transition-duration:0s;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem" class="elem"></div>
```